# I'm trying to Not make my navbar collapse with other sections (My navbar is collapsing with my About us )

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

So I have been trying to make my navbar not collapse with other elements but it seemed like it will not work at all. At the same time, I have to do it Because I have designed my navbar to collapse and expand when clicked on the bars (to make it responsive using media query).

I'm trying to Not make my navbar collapse with other sections (My navbar is collapsing with my About us )I tried doing it position:fixed; but then When the media query for navbar activates the bar image cannot be seen.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/Pawan_Dev_World/pen/wvqZYpw

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.list').click(function(){

        $('nav').toggleClass('active')

    })
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300&display=swap');
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Allura&family=Josefin+Sans:wght@300&display=swap');

  body {
      margin: 0%;
      padding: 0%;
      overflow:hidden;
    }

    /* NavBar */
    
    nav {
      background-color: #E5E5E5;
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
    }
    
    ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    li {
      float: right;
      padding: 2%;
      font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
      color: #ff812c;
      transition: .3s;
    }
    
    a {
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
      color: #ff812c;
      transition: .3s;
    }
    

    
    ul > li:hover {
      background-color: #ff812c;
      
      
      
    }
    
    ul > li:hover a{
      color: rgb(223, 223, 223);
    }

    .list {
      width:20px;
      display:none;
      top: 2%;
      float: right;
      padding: 20px;
      background: #E5E5E5;
      padding-left: 100%;     
      cursor: pointer;

    
    }


  @media screen and (max-width:700px){
    
    nav  {
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      left: -150%;
      top: 60px;
      transition: 0.5s;

    }
    nav.active {
      left: 0%;
    }

    ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }

    

    .list {
      
      display: block;
      
      
    }


    #ul-nav li:first-child{
      order: 4;
    }
    
    #ul-nav li:nth-child(2){
      order: 3;
    }
    
    #ul-nav li:nth-child(3){
      order: 2;
    }
    
    #ul-nav li:nth-child(4){
      order: 1;
    }

  }



  /* Accordin  */


  .container {
      background-color:rgb(223, 223, 223) ;
      padding: 20px;
    
  }


  .acc-h1 {
      font-family: 'Allura', cursive;
  }

  .acco{
      display: flex;
      
      
  }

  .acco-tabs{
      background-color: #ff812c;
      padding: 20px;
      margin: 10px;
      flex: 1 1 0;
    
  }



  @media screen and (max-width:600px) {

      .mvc {
          display: flex;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
      }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- NavBar -->
   
   
            
        <nav class="active">

            <ul id="ul-nav" >
                <li><a href="" class="a-f">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="" class="a-f">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="" class="a-f">Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="a-f">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
            
        </nav>  
        <img src="bars-solid.svg" alt="navbar-list" class="list" >





    <!-- About us -->

 <div class="container" id="about-us">

  <h1 class="acc-h1">About Us</h1>

  <div class="acco">

      <div class="acco-tabs">
      <h3 class="heading-acco">Our Vision</h3>
      <p class="para-acco">Our Vision “Advancing pharmaceutics to enhance human lives” constantly motivates
          us to listen carefully to the customer needs and be acquainted with global needs in
          pharmaceutical and health care sector to produce and deliver outstanding cost effective
          quality products and services that advances human lives.</p>
      </div>


      <div class="acco-tabs">
          <h3 class="heading-acco">Our Mision</h3>
          <p class="para-acco">Our Mission “to do the right things” drives our endeavors to work efficiently at every
              nano level to address today’s challenges in improving health through quality medicines
              by mastering science with advanced technologies.</p>
          
      </div>


      <div class="acco-tabs">
          <h3 class="heading-acco">Our Core Values</h3>
          <p class="para-acco">Trust… Transparency… Integrity... Accountability.</p>
          </div>
      </div>

      <br>


  <p>Vishaura is anchored by a strong and sustainable management that completely
      understands the value of customers and serves beyond their expectations. Known for its
      customer centric approach</p>
      
  </div>
```

Comment: I'm still not quite sure what you're trying to archieve. But for the scrollbar part, you should not use `overflow: hidden` in your CSS if you want browsers to show overflow content in scrollbar instead of "hiding" them

Comment: I'm trying to Not make my navbar collapse with other sections (My navbar is collapsing with my About us )I tried doing it position:fixed; but then When the media query for navbar activates the bar image cannot be seen.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `.active` from nav and `body{overflow-x:hidden;}`. I think you are looking for that. Although you question is not clear.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.list').click(function(){
        $('nav').toggleClass('active')
    })
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300&display=swap');

body {
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

/* NavBar */
nav {
    background-color: #E5E5E5;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
li {
    float: right;
    padding: 2%;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    color: #ff812c;
    transition: .3s;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    color: #ff812c;
    transition: .3s;
}
ul > li:hover {
    background-color: #ff812c;



}
ul > li:hover a{
    color: rgb(223, 223, 223);
}
.list {
    width:20px;
    display:none;
    top: 2%;
    float: right;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #E5E5E5;
    padding-left: 100%;     
    cursor: pointer;
}
@media screen and (max-width:700px){
    nav  {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        left: -150%;
        top: 60px;
        transition: 0.5s;
    }
    nav.active {
        left: 0%;
    }
    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    .list {
        display: block;
    }
    #ul-nav li:first-child{
        order: 4;
    }
    #ul-nav li:nth-child(2){
        order: 3;
    }
    #ul-nav li:nth-child(3){
        order: 2;
    }
    #ul-nav li:nth-child(4){
        order: 1;
    }
}
/* Accordion  */
.container {
    background-color: rgb(223, 223, 223);
    padding: 20px;
}
.acc-h1 {
    font-family: 'Allura', cursive;
}
.acco{
    display: flex;
}
.acco-tabs{
    background-color: #ff812c;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 10px;
    flex: 1 1 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
    .mvc {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- NavBar -->



<nav class="">

    <ul id="ul-nav" >
        <li><a href="" class="a-f">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="a-f">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="a-f">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="a-f">Home</a></li>
    </ul>

</nav>  
<img src="bars-solid.svg" alt="navbar-list" class="list" >


<!-- About us -->
<div class="container" id="about-us">

<h1 class="acc-h1">About Us</h1>

<div class="acco">

<div class="acco-tabs">
<h3 class="heading-acco">Our Vision</h3>
<p class="para-acco">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla facilisis velit vitae tempus porta. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam a rhoncus felis. Mauris gravida ut sem id eleifend. Fusce id mauris ultrices, placerat neque nec, malesuada turpis. Nulla non turpis efficitur, semper turpis et, pulvinar tellus. Morbi quis odio ultrices, bibendum est quis, eleifend enim. Etiam sodales odio a metus dignissim auctor. Praesent venenatis velit sit amet risus congue malesuada. Phasellus scelerisque risus sollicitudin velit hendrerit luctus. Pellentesque eget scelerisque mi, sed ultricies justo. Etiam vitae ligula lorem. Praesent eu urna diam. Sed a sem magna.
    us to listen carefully to the customer needs and be acquainted with global needs in
    pharmaceutical and health care sector to produce and deliver outstanding cost effective
    quality products and services that advances human lives.</p>
</div>


<div class="acco-tabs">
    <h3 class="heading-acco">Our Mision</h3>
    <p class="para-acco">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla facilisis velit vitae tempus porta. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam a rhoncus felis. Mauris gravida ut sem id eleifend. Fusce id mauris ultrices, placerat neque nec, malesuada turpis. Nulla non turpis efficitur, semper turpis et, pulvinar tellus. Morbi quis odio ultrices, bibendum est quis, eleifend enim. Etiam sodales odio a metus dignissim auctor. Praesent venenatis velit sit amet risus congue malesuada. Phasellus scelerisque risus sollicitudin velit hendrerit luctus. Pellentesque eget scelerisque mi, sed ultricies justo. Etiam vitae ligula lorem. Praesent eu urna diam. Sed a sem magna.
        nano level to address today’s challenges in improving health through quality medicines
        by mastering science with advanced technologies.</p>

</div>


<div class="acco-tabs">
    <h3 class="heading-acco">Our Core Values</h3>
    <p class="para-acco">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla facilisis velit vitae tempus porta. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam a rhoncus felis. Mauris gravida ut sem id eleifend. Fusce id mauris ultrices, placerat neque nec, malesuada turpis. Nulla non turpis efficitur, semper turpis et, pulvinar tellus. Morbi quis odio ultrices, bibendum est quis, eleifend enim. Etiam sodales odio a metus dignissim auctor. Praesent venenatis velit sit amet risus congue malesuada. Phasellus scelerisque risus sollicitudin velit hendrerit luctus. Pellentesque eget scelerisque mi, sed ultricies justo. Etiam vitae ligula lorem. Praesent eu urna diam. Sed a sem magna.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<br>


<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla facilisis velit vitae tempus porta. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam a rhoncus felis. Mauris gravida ut sem id eleifend. Fusce id mauris ultrices, placerat neque nec, malesuada turpis. Nulla non turpis efficitur, semper turpis et, pulvinar tellus. Morbi quis odio ultrices, bibendum est quis, eleifend enim. Etiam sodales odio a metus dignissim auctor. Praesent venenatis velit sit amet risus congue malesuada. Phasellus scelerisque risus sollicitudin velit hendrerit luctus. Pellentesque eget scelerisque mi, sed ultricies justo. Etiam vitae ligula lorem. Praesent eu urna diam. Sed a sem magna.h</p>

</div>
```